# How do I style textarea so that it adjusts to the content of that row / div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to change the `textarea` so the submit button and the `textarea` are in the same row.

Originally, I had set it so that the submit button was in the top right of the `div` and the `textarea` was in fitted just perfectly to it's left. I noticed, however, that when I changed the font size of my browser (Chrome), that the position of the button changed and it overflowed to the next row.

Currently I have this: 
[image: InputField]

And I would like the Submit button to be in the top in the top right, regardless of one's browser's settings.

Here's what I have :

```css
form {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  border-right: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
}
#button {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #0084B4;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
}
```

```html
<form name="userForm">
  <textarea name="textarea" rows="3" cols="65" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `cols` in `textarea` HTML tag instead use `width` in CSS and in that `width`, use `calc`, so no matter size of the viewport it will always be side by side

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  border-width:0 1px 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box

}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  width:calc(100% - 102px);
  box-sizing:border-box
    
}
#button {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #0084B4;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 16px;
}
```

```html
<form name="userForm">
  <textarea name="textarea" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So it is okay to use the `rows` attribute?

Comment: Rows are for height so as you wish

Answer (score 0):

When you change viewport size, the proportions probably screwed up. You can avoid this by setting widths, margins and padding in percentages. You can try this:

```
textarea{
    width:60%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

#button {
    width: 30%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this without features of CSS3:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    position: relative;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    margin-right: 6em;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 5em;
}
```

It is also possible to use float instead, but the order of elements in HTML would have to be changed. It is not good to have submit button above the textarea without CSS, so I'm not going to publish it.